# Create a terrain to accomodate a mesh

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a mesh of a track like the one attache [image: attached [1]]I would like to create a terrain like the one below  [image: second picture[2]] that will accomodate the track following the altitude differences and shape of it. Do you have a best procedure to follow?

Thanks

Comment: You can try the *Shrink Wrap* modifier, though it might introduce some distortion to your road

Comment: yeah, it will deform the track, needs something to deform the terrain